# How to test url in soapui

Tags: url, testing, soapui

1.can anybody help me how to test if some URL is working or not? Is it possible to do it via Http request? Unfortunately no tutorial anywhere or help. It should be POST request. I mean how to create test case with assertion response. 
 2.End second question: how to test username and password? How to make test cases? Thanks for help a lot.

Comment: What request are you intending to send? What does URL is working means? You mentioned SoapUI, do you mean with asserting response status?

Comment: @JosephCloude if you want to elaborate on your initial question, you should edit it and include further questions in it. In this case it's better than furthering your question in the comments.